# GitHub Actions install jinja j2

Tags: jinja2, github-actions

Using GitHub Actions, I'm trying to install `j2`:

```yaml
jobs:

  install-packages:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: |
        sudo apt-get install -y jq
        pip3 install --user --upgrade j2cli
        j2 --version
```

This successfully installs j2cli, but the last `j2 --version` produces `Error: Process completed with exit code 127.` ([logs](https://github.com/mihaigalos/docker/pull/26/checks?check_run_id=1405515565)).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute your script using a `run` step it is executed in a [`bash` shell](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-running-a-script-using-bash) by default. The error code `127` is emitted by shell when the given command is not found within your `PATH` environment variable and it is not a built-in shell command. In other words, the system doesn't understand your command, because it doesn't know where to find the `j2` command you're trying to call. When we know what the error means we can fix it by adding `pip3` package installation directory to the `PATH`. We can do it manually by locating the path by calling `pip3 show j2cli` or we can set up a Python environment to do it automatically using a dedicated [`setup-python` action](https://github.com/actions/setup-python#usage) before calling `pip3` installer. Having that in mind the script should be adjusted:

```yaml
jobs:
  install-packages:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.x
    - run: |
        pip3 install --user --upgrade j2cli
        j2 --version
```

It should fix the error.

Please note we don't need to install `jq` binary as it comes pre-installed with the GitHub-hosted runner. That's why you don't need the:

```
sudo apt-get install -y jq
```

If we look at the [log included](https://github.com/mihaigalos/docker/pull/26/checks?check_run_id=1405515565#step:2:11) we can see it clearly

```
jq is already the newest version (1.5+dfsg-2).
```

You can find the software included with the GitHub-hosted runner [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md#installed-software).